# How to insert dropdown list items into database table using ASP.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please I need you to help me to solve one kind of problem. I have tried to insert selected dropdown list items into SQL database table but did not work correctly the data are saving but saved only Id instead to save CountryName, StateName, and CityName. I have four tables Country table, State Table, City table, and Stafftbl table. I am using ASP.Net Core with entity framework core.

Country table

| CountryId | CountryName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | America |
| 2 | India |

State table

| StateId | StateName | CountryId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | California | 1 |

City table

| CityId | CityName | StateId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alameda | 1 |

I want insert `CountryName`, `StateName` and `CityName` from selected dropdown list items into `Stafftbl` table, as shown in the example here. My dropdown lists are working fine.

Stafftbl table

| StaffId | StaffName | Phone | Email | CountryName | StateName | CityName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dauda Muhd | +12309 | em@gmail.com | America | California | Alameda |

Model: CascadingModel

```
public class CascadingModel
{
    public CascadingModel()
    {
        this.Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.States = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.Cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public string StaffName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller: DropdownController

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel();

        model.Countries = (from c in this.Context.Countries
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Value = c.CountryId.ToString(),
                               Text = c.CountryName
                           }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value)
    {
        CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel();

        switch (type)
        {
            case "ddlCountries":
                model.States = (from customer in _context.States
                                where customer.CountryId == value
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = customer.StateId.ToString(),
                                    Text = customer.StateName
                                }).ToList();
                break;

            case "ddlStates":
                model.Cities = (from customer in _context.Cities
                                where customer.StateId == value
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = customer.CityId.ToString(),
                                    Text = customer.CityName
                                }).ToList();
                break;
        }

        return Json(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CascadingModel cascadingModel)
    {
        var model = new StaffDetailVM()
        {
            StaffId = cascadingModel.StaffId,
            StaffName = cascadingModel.StaffName,
            PhoneNumber = cascadingModel.PhoneNumber,
            Email = cascadingModel.Email,
            CountryName = cascadingModel.CountryName,
            StateName = cascadingModel.StateName,
            CityName = cascadingModel.CityName,
        };

        if (model != null)
        {
            await _context.Stafftbl.AddAsync(model);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return View(cascadingModel);
    }
```

View `Index.cshtml`:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Dropdown" asp-action="Index" >
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StaffId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StaffId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StaffId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StaffName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StaffName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StaffName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CountryId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="ddlCountries" name="CountryName" asp-for="CountryId" asp-items="Model.Countries" class="form-control">
               <option value="">--Please select--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CountryId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StateId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="ddlStates" name="StateName" asp-for="StateId" asp-items="Model.States" class="form-control">
               <option value="">--Please select--</option>
             </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="StateId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
             <select id="ddlCities" name="CityName" asp-for="CityId" asp-items="Model.Cities" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">--Please select--</option>
              </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CityId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" asp-action="SaveStaff" formnovalidate class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" asp-action="SaveUpdate" formnovalidate class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to insert selected dropdown list items into SQL database
> table but did not work correctly the data are saving but saved only Id
> instead to save CountryName, StateName, and CityName.

That is because your dropdownlist's option value is set with `XXXId` instead of `XXXName`.

Change your code below:

```
Countries = (from c in this.Context.Countries
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.CountryName,
                    Text = c.CountryName
                }).ToList(),
model.States = (from customer in _context.States
                        where customer.CountryId == value
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = customer.StateName,
                            Text = customer.StateName
                }).ToList();

model.Cities = (from customer in _context.Cities
                            where customer.StateId == value
                            select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = customer.CityName,
                            Text = customer.CityName
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank Rena, I have tried your suggestion and observed is working when you are using a single dropdown. But if you are using another dropdown on the change event did not work because is using the id to populate the data. 
In short Based on your suggestion `Country` dropdown worked but `State`. and `City` dropdowns did not come up with the data.

Comment: Hi @dausa, guessing you use ajax to call the State and City dropdown. Could you pls share the ajax also.

Comment: Hi @Rena. I observed you did not understand my comment. My Ajax working fine changing `Value = c.CountryId'` to  `Value = c.CountryName` is why the dropdown list did not come up. But necessity made used one arrangement and is working, I called selected dropdown list items into Inputbox using this line of code  `$("#statename").val($("#ddlStates option:selected").text());`  from input box to database.

Comment: Hi @dausa , so what is your code. Explain to your requirement with code. If your previous question has been resolved, suggest you ask a new question and accept the answer. If not, pls edit the question for more details.

Comment: Hi @Rena. `statename` is my inputbox id and `ddlStates`  is my State dropdown id so I use this  `$("#statename").val($("#ddlStates option:selected").text());` in ajax and the data populated in dropdown equally populated in inputbox

Comment: Hi @dausa, not understand why your issue related with the input box... Your first comment said the other two dropdowns do not work...So I need know how do you render the dropdown. For your second comment, you said your ajax working fine but dropdown does not come up, have your check if you set the option value with something like: `responsedata.countryName` instead of `countryId`? For your input box, I never see you use it in the code and do not related to your previous question.

Comment: Hi @Rena. Initially, in my question, I said I have tried to insert selected dropdown list items into SQL database table but did not work correctly the data are saving but saved only Id instead to save CountryName, StateName, and CityName. My dropdown lists are working fine.  So since I found it very difficult to insert selected dropdowns into the database that is why I used the inputbox and the inputbox help insert the data into the database. Using this code `$("#statename").val($("#ddlStates option:selected").text()); ` here is my ajax code

Comment: no space to put ajax in comment space.

Comment: Hi @dausa, I really suggest you read my answer more carefully. Any way, I will say again, pls edit your previous question to share your code with your explanation for the requirement...